# Losing my Access DB password on compact, how to reset from VB?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

First time poster here...

My VB.NET program compacts and repairs my DB, but somewhere in the process unsets the database password. No problem, just reset it through VB, right? Ummm... not sure how to go about that task.

So I either need to know how to compact it without losing the password, or how to reset the password after I lose it.

Trying the best I can to make the code look decent in my post, let me know if there is a better way.

Thanks!

```
Dim strAccessDatabasePath As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "App_Data\Squirrel.accdb"        
Dim LockedDbFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(strAccessDatabasePath.Replace(".accdb", ".laccdb"))        
Dim TempFolder As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "App_Data\temp"        
Dim TempDB As String = TempFolder & "\temp.accdb"

If LockedDbFileInfo.Exists Then            
    MsgBox("Database is in use. Please make sure no users are in the database before performing maintenance.")        
Else            
    MsgBox("This program has detected no current database users and will proceed with database maintenance.")        
End If  

Try            
    Directory.CreateDirectory(TempFolder)        
Catch ex As Exception            
    MsgBox("There has been an error creating a temporary directory in your application directory. Please check credentials and try again.")        
End Try  

Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now        
Dim format As String = "MMM d yyyy HHmmss "        
Dim TempDateTime As String = time.ToString(format)         

'Copy DB to backup directory.        
Try            
    File.Copy(strAccessDatabasePath, txtDBbackupFolder.Text & "\" & "DBbkup " & TempDateTime & ".accdb")        
Catch ex As Exception            
    MsgBox("There was an issue writing to the backup folder. Please check credentials and try again.")        
End Try    

'Copy DB to temp directory for maintenance.        
File.Copy(strAccessDatabasePath, TempFolder & "\" & "temp.accdb")        
File.Delete(strAccessDatabasePath)         
Dim JROEng As Object         
JROEng = CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine")         
JROEng.CompactDatabase("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TempDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=woodkitten70;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5", "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
strAccessDatabasePath & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")         
'connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\Squirrel.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXXXXXXXX" 

Try            
    Kill(TempFolder & "\*.*")        
Catch ex As Exception            
    'MsgBox(ex.Message)        
End Try         
Directory.Delete(TempFolder)`
```

Comment: Can't help with the question but two notes about your code - `Kill` is VB6 and should be updated to something like: `For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles` and you should not post your DB password (I have editied it out)

Comment: As far as the password goes, it's out there in the wild already (and it was in more than one place in the code). It should be changed.

Comment: Access database passwords are just security theater in the first place, and of little of no value for any purpose whatsoever. Maybe the compact is doing you a favor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you refer to the Access interop and use that compact repair?
"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass.CompactRepair(String, String, [Boolean]) As Boolean"

```
Public Overridable Function CompactRepair(ByVal SourceFile As String, ByVal DestinationFile As String, Optional ByVal LogFile As Boolean = False) As Boolean
```

Member of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Was stuck for a while because I never closed the instance of that class at the end, but once I got onto that track I was okay. THANKS!